# FIRESTORE : Query Stream With Multiple where clause

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I hope you are well.

Here I have created a filter system in my application, I have a **List filters** on which I apply a forEach iteration and each String filter of this iteration is added in the Where clause which retrieve all the documents whose section field corresponds to one of the String filter of my Firestore query.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
Stream<List<Article>> filteredArticles() async* {
    List<String> filters = ['Sport', 'Santé'];
    final articlesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('REVIEWS');
    Stream<List<Article>> filteredArticles;
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> queryStream;

    await Future.forEach(filters, (filter) async {
      queryStream = articlesCollection
          .where('section', isEqualTo: filter)
          .orderBy('createdDate', descending: true)
          .snapshots();

      filteredArticles = queryStream.map(_convertToArticleList);
    });

    yield* filteredArticles;
  }
```

Method to map QuerySnapshot to List of article

```
List<Article> _convertToArticleList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Article.fromMap(doc.data());
    }).toList();
  }
```

Method to convert firestore document data to a Article class

```
factory Article.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final id = data[Fields.id];
    final imagesLinks = data[Fields.imagesLinks];
    final createdDate = data[Fields.createdDate];
    final date = data[Fields.date];
    final title = data[Fields.title];
    final details = data[Fields.details];
    final section = data[Fields.section];
    final link = data[Fields.link];
    final likes = data[Fields.likes];
    return Article(
      id: id,
      imagesLinks: imagesLinks,
      createdDate: createdDate,
      details: details,
      date: date,
      title: title,
      section: section,
      link: link,
      likes: likes,
    );
  }
```

Here is my database, it currently contains 3 documents of which 2 have the section field corresponding to one of the filters (Sport, Santé).

[image: first database image]

[image: second database image]

The problem is that I receive only one document instead of 2 and it depends on the position of the filter in the table, i.e. if I put Health in the first position of my table, I receive only the document with the section field corresponding to Health and the same if I put Sport in the first position of the table, I receive only the document with the section field corresponding to Sport instead of 2 at the same time.

My goal is to retrieve all the documents whose section field corresponds to one of the String filter in my List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a field's value is equal to any of the desired set of values, you can use Array-Membership based filtering: [Source](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#filtering) (Check the array queries section)

Use the filter list `filters` in your firestore query as follows:

```
queryStream = articlesCollection
          .where('section', arrayContainsAny: filters)
          .orderBy('createdDate', descending: true)
          .snapshots();
```

Comment: By doing this : 

```queryStream = articlesCollection.where(Fields.section, arrayContainsAny: filters).orderBy(Fields.createdDate, descending: true).snapshots();```

I don't get data.

Comment: But there are matching in section field

Comment: Wait a minute, my section field is not an Array, will it work?

Comment: Your section field is not an array. You are checking whether the value of 'section' is  equal to any of the elements in the list of desired values.

Comment: Also, please mark the answer as accepted as I see you've adopted the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research, I managed to find a solution by reading the FlutterFire documentation.
Here is what I did:
I changed the type of my field section from `String` to `List<String>` which contains just one element which is my keyword (my filter).

And then to filter my results, I use the parameter arrayContainsAny of the where method of Firestore on which I pass my `List<String> filters`

```
Stream<List<Article>> filteredArticles;
Stream<QuerySnapshot> queryStream;
List<String> filters = ['Sport', 'Health'];

  queryStream = articlesCollection
      .where(Fields.section, arrayContainsAny: filters)
      .orderBy(Fields.createdDate, descending: true)
      .snapshots();

  filteredArticles = queryStream.map(_convertToArticleList);
```

I hope this will help someone who will have the same problem as I have. Thanks